# Staging an intervention(collocation)

Tags: collocations

I came across this collocation just a few minutes ago, then as I was looking up to it online, I can't find the meaning of it. Only intervention or staging, which means not as a combined words.

> **Staging an intervention** to reverse the effect of global warming is a brilliant idea.

What do you mean by this? Is it:

- planning a method step by step
- or staging=introducing

Since this has not been asked yet, I believe the site and learners would benefit from this. Please help to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*stage*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stage#h2):

> **2** : to produce or cause to happen for public view or public effect
>   // *stage* a track meet
>   // *stage* a hunger strike

Although an intervention is not normally a public spectacle (if talking about, for instance, an intervention for a specific person), the verb is used in the same way.

In this case, it does seem to be used to describe a public spectacle. The people involved would be *organizing*, *putting together*, or *holding* an intervention.